# Is there any practical difference between double pipe || and singleton in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I was yesterday reading about Ruby and reached the concept of Singleton, which mentioned was used to avoid instantiating a class more than once.

I didn't know about this concept before but when I wanted to achieve that purpose I was creating a global variable and using the double pipe || instead.

eg:

```
@browser ||= Browser.new
```

Is there any difference, or advantage in some situations, which would make the usage of Singleton better?

Comment: They don't have much in common. A singleton class can be instantiated only once. In your case, I can make as many instances as I like: `@browser1 ||= Browser.new; @browser2 ||= Browser.new`

Comment: Ah, I see what you  mean now. Thanks for the comment. If you want to put the comment as an answer I'll mark it as resolved. 

I was confusing things...

Comment: FYI: `@browser` is an _instance_ variable, [global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Global+Variables) start with a `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I forgot some concepts... :(

Comment: @mickael : BTW, for various possibilities to implement Singleton classes, have a look [here](https://practicingruby.com/articles/ruby-and-the-singleton-pattern-dont-get-along). I usually use the `extend self` trick described in that article for creating Singleton classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||=` operator in Ruby sets a value to a variable if the variable is undefined or contains a falsey value (nil or false).

```
a = 1
a ||= 2 # a is already set to 1 so it stays 1.

a = false
a ||= 1 # a was falsey, it is now set to 1.
```

This is often used to memoize method return values to reduce unnecessary recomputation:

```
class Foo
  def value
    @value ||= 1+1
  end
end

Foo.new.value # @value was undefined so it set to 1+1 = 2
Foo.new.value # @value was already defined so return it instead of recalculating
```

A singleton class is a class that can only have one instance.

A regular non singleton class:

```
class Foo
end

# create two instances:
foo1 = Foo.new
foo2 = Foo.new

foo1 == foo2 # => false
```

A singleton class:

```
require 'singleton'
class Foo
  include Singleton

  def test
    "hello"
  end
end

# you can't create an instance:
foo = Foo.new # => NoMethodError (private method `new' called for Foo:Class)

# there is one global instance:
foo1 = Foo.instance
foo2 = Foo.instance
foo1 == foo2 # => true

# the Singleton module does not enable you to call the instance methods directly:
Foo.test # => NoMethodError (private method `test' called for Foo:Class)
Foo.instance.test # => "hello"
```

I don't think there are many cases where a singleton class is actually the best solution to a problem.

Comment: I could think about cases where a singleton could be useful, eg, for creating a `@logger variable to capture log errors, but in our case, we were always using the `@logger variable so it seems the final result was similar to use different variables which instantiated the same singleton class so I couldn't see the benefit so clearly for small teams where we all know what we are using in our test framework.

Answer (score 2):

`||=` is used to [*memoize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) a value. For example, if you have a method performing an expensive operation or returning a varying value:

```
class Foo
  def now
    Time.now
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:59 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 12:00:02 +0200
```

And you would like to cache that value, `||=` is your friend:

```
class Foo
  def now
    @now ||= Time.now
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
```

The first call invokes `Time.now` and assigns the result to `@now`. Subsequent calls just return `@now` without evaluating the right-hand side. Therefore, `Time.now` is only called once and the method's return value doesn't change any more.

And because `@now` is an *instance* variable, a separate value is stored per instance:

```
f = Foo.new
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200

g = Foo.new
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 12:00:02 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 12:00:02 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 12:00:02 +0200
```

A [*singleton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on the other hand ensures that there's one (and only one) instance of a given class (per process), e.g.:

```
require 'singleton'

class Foo
  include Singleton

  def now
    @now ||= Time.now
  end
end

f = Foo.instance
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
f.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200

g = Foo.instance
g.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
g.now #=> 2018-06-21 11:59:56 +0200
```

That's because `f` and `g` refer to the very same object. Including [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) removes the ability to create any other instances via `new` or `allocate`:

```
Foo.new      #=> NoMethodError
Foo.allocate #=> NoMethodError
```

Comment: Well often `||=` is used to memoize, but what it really does is set a value to a variable unless the variable already contains a truthy value.

Comment: @KimmoLehto sure, but I thought an example might be more helpful since the OP is asking for practical differences, not for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks so much both, really clear the difference with the examples. Really well explained.